# How to allow whitespace in email string in swift?

Tags: ios, regex, email

I have a email text field in which i am entering the email adderess. Now if i enter a space at the end of email address then still it is considered as invalid email.But this should not be as user can by mistake enter such input and i should trim the space at end or begin.

I am using below code for checking the validation.Please tell me the best solution for this ?

```
var isValidEmail: Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}" //"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
}
```

Comment: Just use `trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` instead of self

Comment: @rmaddy why did you remove the Swift tag?

Comment: @Leo Because the question isn't about Swift. It's about regular expressions.

Comment: @rmaddy It is implemented as a Swift String extension and can be solved without changing the regex itself

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, please consider accepting. Please also consider upvoting the answers that proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a pattern that will allow trailing whitespace chars:

```
let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}\\s*"
                                                                    ^^^
```

The `\s*` pattern matches 0 or more whitespace characters.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/YPoAJJ/1).

Your pattern will match:

- start of string (it is implicit in the patterns used with `MATCHES`)
- `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, and the symbols sepcified in the character class
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9.-]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars, `.` or/and `-` chars
- `\\.` - a dot
- `[A-Za-z]{2,64}` - 2 to 64 ASCII letters
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function.

```
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: candidate.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
}
```